# Registro usuarios

Tags: php

estoy con un pequeño/sencillo sistema de registro de usuarios en una BD Postgress y estoy teniendo problemas puesto que no me hace el INSERT en la tabla, me arroja siempre el error de "Error creando el usuario".
Código registro.php.

```
include_once 'conexion.php';
    $conexion = new Conexion();
    $conn = $conexion->getConexion();
    
    
    $message = '';
    
    if(!empty($_POST['usuario']) && !empty($_POST['password']) && !empty($_POST['id_role'])){
        $sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios (username, password, id_role) VALUES (:usuario, :password, :id_role)";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(':usuario', $_POST['usuario']);
        $password = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
        $stmt->bindParam(':password', $password);
        $stmt->bindParam(':id_role', $_POST['id_role']);
        $stmt->execute();
    
        if ($stmt->execute()){
            $message = 'Creado nuevo usuario';
        }else{
            $message = 'Error creando el usuario';
        }
    }
```

Código del formulario

```
<form method="post" action="registro.php" name="signup">
    <label>Username</label>
    <input id= "usuario" type="text" name="usuario" autocomplete="off" />
    <label>Password</label>
    <input id="password" type="password" name="password" autocomplete="off"/>
    <select id="id_role" name="id_role" class="role">
        <option>Seleccionar Rol...</option>
        <option value="1">Propietario</option>
        <option value="2">Invitado</option>
    </select>
    <div class="errorMsg"><?php echo $message; ?></div>
    <input type="submit" class="button">
</form>
```

Comment: Si te manda error creando el usuario, significa que tu `$stmt->execute()` esta retornando false. En este punto, justo antes del execute, imprime la consulta a ver como la estas realizando.

Comment: hago ` print $password; print $_POST['usuario']; print $_POST['id_role'];` y me imprime $2y$10$s.c.rs2nk9pC4Bkozca.9u8Bxj/.5kLqAzrd8o4N8mwqYmjpdr6viusuario2, todo junto. El name= usuario id_role=2 lo anterior se supone que lo encriptó bien.

Comment: Donde haces eso???, cuando haces eso ??? Yo te pregunte sobre la consulta entera, no sobre 2 variables POST

Comment: hago un var_dump para ver que me trae: `object(PDOStatement)#3 (1) { ["queryString"]=> string(90) "INSERT INTO usuarios (username, password, id_role) VALUES (:username, :password, :id_role)" }`